# SQL Server : select rows with time stamp values near values in subquery

Tags: sql-server, union, common-table-expression

I have a log table that includes id, TimeStamp, Message where the `Message` value sometimes contains 'WARNING'.

```
SELECT TimeStamp 
FROM Logs 
WHERE Message LIKE '%WARNING%'
```

What I need are the rows that are within 5 minutes on either side of the times in that set. I know `BETWEEN` with `DATEADD` -5 minutes and +5 minutes can do that for single values.

How can I do it for a set of values? I there a way to combine a CTE and a UNION ALL or am I going to have to cursor through the result set?

**UPDATE**

I tried this attempt at using CTE.

```
declare @searchTerm varchar(50) = '%WARNING%';
declare @searchDate datetime = '2023-11-01';
declare @id int;
declare @eventTime datetime;
declare @lowRange int = -5;
declare @highRange int = 5;

WITH cteEvents as (
    select Id, EventTime from Veneer.dbo.Logs where EventMessage LIKE @searchTerm and EventTime > @searchDate
)
SELECT * 
    from Logs l
    left outer join cteEvents ev on l.Id=ev.Id 
    where l.EventTime between DATEADD(MINUTE, @lowRange, ev.EventTime) and DATEADD(MINUTE, @highRange, ev.EventTime)
```

The end result is only records with the search term WARNING. None of the surrounding records within the time period appear. I tried `INNER`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins. I tried it with each one being first or last.
TIA - Mike

Comment: is your table really large and is the ID consecutive and what are the odds of getting more than for example 100 messages in 5 minutes?

Comment: The table is about 1.5m records, the result set in which I'm interested is only for the last few weeks - about 25k since 01 Nov 2023. And the warning records are much less than that. I developed a solution that puts the warning records in a temp table, then a cursor to run through it and get the items surrounding it with the dateadd functions. It takes about 2 seconds to select ~ 1500 records.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need for a CTE. Get all WARNING logs, then join to any within 5 mins of the warning on either side with a BETWEEN.

```
declare @logs table([sid] int not null identity, [timestamp] datetime, [message] nvarchar(100));

insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST1');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST2');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST3');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST4');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'WARNING: TEST5');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST6');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST7');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST8');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'TEST9');
insert into @logs values(DATEADD(MINUTE, -25, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), N'WARNING: TEST10');

WITH CTE AS
(
    select [timestamp]--get distinct dates
    from
        @logs l
    where
        [message] like '%WARNING%'
    group by    
        [timestamp]
)
SELECT l.*
FROM 
    CTE lw
    inner join @logs l on 
        l.[timestamp] between DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, lw.[timestamp]) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, lw.[timestamp])
```

Comment: watch out for duplicates!

Comment: UGH, fixed the dupe issue, thanks @siggemannen

Comment: I'm not sure about the `group by [timestamp]` because all these have discrete time stamps down to the ms. So group by will almost certainly be single row each, unless we do rounding on it somehow.
I tried something similar to your join but for some reason it only showed the ones with WARNING. I try again and maybe update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
declare @searchTerm varchar(50) = '%WARNING%';
declare @searchStart datetime = '2023-01-10';
declare @searchEnd datetime = '2023-11-01';
declare @lowRange int = -10;
declare @highRange int = 5;

WITH partOne as (
    select Id, EventTime from Veneer.dbo.Logs where EventMessage LIKE @searchTerm and EventTime between @searchStart and @searchEnd
),
partTwo as (
    select distinct evLogs.Id
    from partOne, Logs evLogs where evLogs.EventTime between DATEADD(MINUTE, @lowRange, partOne.EventTime) and DATEADD(MINUTE, @highRange, partOne.EventTime)
)
SELECT * from Logs inner join partTwo on Logs.id=partTwo.Id order by Logs.Id
```

The partOne and Logs are selected without a join otherwise it's limited by the ones in partOne. This runs horribly slow unless there's an index on the EventTime. Using a temp table and a cursor is actually faster.

With a set of 334911 records between the search dates and 19789 warnings:
Temp table and cursor method - 1:15,
CTE method without index - 3:03,
CTE with index on EventTime - 0:01

**Edit: On closer examination I realized there were duplicates in the result. Added `distinct` to selection of Id in partTwo and join in the final selection. Fixed result count**

Mike